# Unity problem with ConfigurableJoint, how fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

There is a chain of units that are attached to each other using CongigurableJoint.(RotationUnit - top unit, HeadAttachment - bottom unit). The bottom chain has all axes locked, but it still ignores these settings and is not axis-locked. You can see in the picture what I'm talking about. Also, in the picture, the settings for the lower unit are attached on the left and the settings for the upper unit are attached on the right.
Can you please tell me what this could be and how it can be fixed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zehf3.jpg)

The second unit must be rigidly attached to the first unit. It will only attach normally if Sweep Body is checked. If anything, this is only part of the chain, there are more links before and after it